# Pygame go to nearest sprite (AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x')

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I'm trying to do a program where you spawn "scots" with a click and then they go to the nearest one of them. As you can see in my code i have an "impact" function, the problem is right there.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import os

ANCHO = 800
ALTO = 800

WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.font.init()

scot_ancho = int(ANCHO / 15)
scot_alto = int(ALTO / 15)

scot_image = pygame.image.load("scot.jpg")
scot_scaled = pygame.transform.smoothscale(scot_image,(scot_ancho,scot_alto))

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ANCHO,ALTO))

class Scot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = scot_scaled.convert()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

    def impact(self):

        #Where the proplem is

        enemy = min([e for e in all_sprites], key=lambda e: pow(e.rect.x-self.x, 2) + pow(e.rect.y-self.y, 2))

        return enemy

    def update(self):

        Scot.impact(enemy)

        for sprite in all_sprites:
            if sprite is self:
                a = 1
                continue
            if self.rect.colliderect(sprite.rect):
                a = 0
                break

        destination_x = enemy[0]
        destination_y = enemy[1]

        if self.rect.x == destination_x:
            pass
        else:
            if self.rect.x < destination_x:
                self.rect.x += 1 * a
            else:
                self.rect.x -= 1 * a

        if self.rect.y == destination_y:
            pass
        else:
            if self.rect.y < destination_y:
                self.rect.y += 1 * a
            else:
                self.rect.y -= 1 * a

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:

    ventana.fill(BLACK)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            scot = Scot()
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            scot.rect.x = mouse_pos[0] - scot_ancho / 2
            scot.rect.y = mouse_pos[1] - scot_alto / 2
            all_sprites.add(scot)

    all_sprites.update()

    all_sprites.draw(ventana)

    clock.tick(30)
    pygame.display.update()
```

As you can see if you execute this i get "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'x'" why is that? Isn't "e" supposed to be a sprite? Why can't i call it's rect?

Comment: `self.rect.x` instead of `self.x` and `self.rect.y` instead of `self.y`

Comment: so `pow(e.rect.x-self.rect.x, 2) + pow(e.rect.y-self.rect.y, 2))`? that gets me the same error

Comment: `self.impact(enemy)` instead of `Scot.impact(enemy)`. Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The position of the object is stored in the `rect` attribute. `self.rect.x` instead of `self.x` and `self.rect.y` instead of `self.y` in the following line of code:

<s>`enemy = min([e for e in all_sprites], key=lambda e: pow(e.rect.x-self.x, 2) + pow(e.rect.y-self.y, 2))`</s>

```py
enemy = min(
    [e for e in all_sprites], 
    key=lambda e: pow(e.rect.x-self.rect.x, 2) + pow(e.rect.y-self.rect.y, 2))
```

`impact` is a method object. So `self.impact(enemy)` instrad of `Scot.impact(enemy)`:

```py
class Scot(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # [...]

    def update(self):

        self.impact(enemy)

        # [...]
```